# RelativeLayout inside ScrollView only puts widgets into the screen box

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Is it possible to use long lists of widgets inside RelativeLayout, which in turn is wrapped into ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="800dp"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="800dp"
         >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/screen_size_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/screen_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/screen_size_label2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/screen_size_label"
            android:layout_below="@+id/screen_size_label"
            android:text="@string/screen_size_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/screen_size_label3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/screen_size_label"
            android:layout_below="@+id/screen_size_label2"
            android:text="@string/screen_size_label" />

        // each following child uses android:layout_below="@+id/previous"
```

When I paste considerable amount of widgets so that the bottom of the screen is achieved the next don't get placed under the previous ones, as I expected, but instead they try to fit in  the screen-box resulting in mess. What I need instead is to place them one under another - so that those that don't fit into screen-box become accessible through scrolling.

It works fine when I use LinearLayout instead of RellativeLayout, however I'd like to get use of RelativeLayout if it's possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use `android:layout_height="800dp"`? Just use `"wrap_content"` and everything should work fine.

Comment: I think in those layout_align_left and layout_below you are always adding new id's (@+id/ should create a new id, @id/ references an existing one), instead of referencing existing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the height of `Scrollview` and `RelativeLayout` to "fill_`parent`"

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the height of the `Scrollview` and `RelativeLayout` ..

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
```

Comment: There must be more to it, since adding the above code still results in a piled up mess for me, despite using layout_below etc...

Answer (score 0):

You define scrollview's height and relativelayout's height to same, then its' no need to scroll. So you change scrollview's height to fill_parent, and relativelayout's height to wrap_content.